# How would I go about moving /usr to a different partition

Tags: release-juno

I would like to move /usr to a different partition because I would like to not use that much space on my ssd in favor of my fairly empty hdd. I would also like to move another /snap since it eats up alot of space as well. I know I could just physically move it but would all the programs that use it automatically be updated to point towards the new directory? Will new applications still go to the moved /usr or would it create a new one on the SSD and use that again? On ver 5.0.

Answer (score 1):

Moving the directory to a different partition won't work. The best solution would probably be to do this during the installation process.

You need to create 3 separate partitions, 1 on the SSD with `/` mountpoint and the other two on the hard drive with mount points `/usr` and `/snap`.

It is also a good practise to have `/home` directory on a separate partion, it helps a lot when reinstalling os or changing a linux distro. And it's also good to have a Swap partition.

I wouldn't recommend doing this on a running system.

For more info on this you can see
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/partitioning#Partition_scheme